# Nexus OSS - How can i add branch name and build no along with the rpm package name and push it to nexus oss?

Tags: jenkins, build, jenkins-pipeline, nexus, rpm

I have a jenkins build which generates an rpm and this rpm is deployed to nexus oss repo for storage using the following command.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.company.app.rpm.snapshot -DartifactId=$RPM_NAME -Dversion=$RPM_VERSION -DgeneratePom=true -Dpackaging=rpm -DrepositoryId=ReleaseCandidate -Durl=${NEXUS_URL}/ReleaseCandidate -Dfile=$rpm
```

This works great. Currently this is set such that when the master branch on tfs-git creates an rpm, it gets send to the Nexus OSS using this command.

But what I want to do now is to make this possible for each feature branch as well. I want to get the feature branch name as well as the jenkins build no that generated that rpm to be also part of the rpm in the nexus oss. For this i tried editing the artifactId=$RPM_NAME and made it to

```
-DartifactId=${BRANCH_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}_${RPM_NAME}
```

But apparently this format is not allowed and it throws the error

```
 'artifactId' with value 'branchname_18' does not match a valid id pattern.[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

I need advice from you guys. How can i make the branch name and build no available in the nexus repo along with the rpm generated for that branch and respective build number.

Thanks a lot in advance !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way myself, and its by far the easiest one, you have the version id property in the mvn deploy:delpoy file syntax . If we edit this to include the branch name and the build no the it easily gets added on to the the rpm name. In my case I did it like this :

-Dversion=${RPM_VERSION}-${BRANCH_NAME}_${BUILD_NUMBER}-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 0):

I use a `Makefile` to call `rpmbuild` that does non-Jenkins-specific git stuff to get the branch name:

```
GIT_BRANCH:=$(notdir $(shell git name-rev --name-only HEAD | perl -pe 's/[~^]+\d*$$//'))
```

This allows my team to build the RPMs for testing on their local boxes. Then to add a Jenkins build number (in the `Makefile`):

```
COMMIT_TAG=%{nil}
( ... cut ... )
  # Get Jenkins number in there too
  ifneq "$(BUILD_NUMBER)" ""
    COMMIT_TAG+=_J$(BUILD_NUMBER)
  endif
  ifneq "$(GIT_BRANCH)" "undefined"
    ifneq "$(GIT_BRANCH)" "master"
      COMMIT_TAG+=_$(shell echo $(GIT_BRANCH)|tr - _)
    endif
  endif
```

So that puts the Jenkins build number "`_J000`" and then a non-`master` branch name (with no hyphens) into `COMMIT_TAG`. Later:

```
export COMMIT_TAG
rpmbuild --define="COMMIT_TAG $(shell echo "$(COMMIT_TAG)" | tr -d ' ')"
```

So now there's an RPM macro of the same name. In the RPM specfile (my `Makefile` also sets others like `RPM_RELEASE` and optionally `RELEASE_TAG`):

```
Release: %{RPM_RELEASE}%{?RELEASE_TAG}%{?COMMIT_TAG}%{?dist}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I was wondering if there is some way to get the branch name and build no into nexus using the mvn deploy command line itself.